# Obtener nombre de un archivo

Tags: java, servlets

Estoy realizando una app web con jsp, intento  hacer un formulario que incluye un foto de esta manera

```
<form name="AddCat" action="../Insertar" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Este formulario se envia  aun servlet que soporta multipart

```
@WebServlet(name = "Insertar", urlPatterns = {"/Insertar"})
@MultipartConfig
```

Y en el método dopost realizo lo siguiente

```
String nombre=request.getParameter("nombreCat");
Part archivo = request.getPart("archivos"); //para el input que contiene la foto
InputStream streamArchivo = archivo.getInputStream();
   //EL if solo es para checar que haya recibido algo jeje
   if(streamArchivo!=null)
   {                
    System.out.println("recibió");
   }

   else 
    System.out.println("vació");

   System.out.println(nombre);
```

Ya que recibí ese archivo que al parecer si lo hace, me gustaría poner obtener la extencion del archivo y la ruta donde se encuentra para poder copiarlo a una carpeta especial dentro  de mi proyecto, alguna idea ? Gracias

Comment: Offtopic: No es necesario poner `../` en el action de los formularios porque los servlets mapean rutas **relativas**, donde `/` es el context path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza [`Part#getSubmittedFileName`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/Part.html#getSubmittedFileName--).

Ten en cuenta que la única información que se envía es el nombre del archivo. Desde el servidor, no vas a conocer la ruta completa donde se encuentra el archivo de lado del cliente, principalmente porque no es información relevante para el servidor y por temas de seguridad (no vas a revelar información tan particular del cliente).

Si necesitas copiarlo en una ruta dentro de tu proyecto, te recomiendo que crees una carpeta en el servidor y deposites allí el contenido del archivo que se encuentra en el `InputStream`.

```
File carpetaDestino = new File("/alguna/ruta/en/el/servidor");
File archivoDestino = new File(carpetaDestino, archivo.getSubmittedFileName());
InputStream streamArchivo = archivo.getInputStream();
Files.copy(streamArchivo, archivoDestino .toPath());
```

---

Para colocar las rutas del action en los formularios, lo mejor es utilizar `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` y así tener rutas absolutas independientemente de dónde se encuentre el recurso.

Cambia esto:

```html
<form name="AddCat" action="../Insertar" ...>
                            ^
                            |-- malo!
```

Por esto:

```html
<form name="AddCat" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Insertar" ...>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias =)  estoy trabajando en ello pero tengo una duda  para obtener el nombre del archivo  hice lo siguiente 
String nombre=archivo.getName(); 
pero esta linea solo obtiene el nombre del campo input donde este el archivo no el nombre del archivo como tal gracias

Comment: @MissaelArmenta lo siento, tienes razón. Acabo de actualizar la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias me ha servido bastante,  solo otra cosa jejeje soy nuevo en esto lamento preguntar tanto jajaja y agradezco mucho que te tomes el tiempo para responder en fin existe forma de solo obtener la extencion del archivo ? he buscado en la documentación de la clase pero no encuentro algun metodo que extraiga solo la extencion

Comment: @MissaelArmenta eso de "extensión" de archivo es una (!@#$%&) mala idea que da Windows a sus usuarios. Un archivo en sí no tiene extensión, es más la "extensión" es irrelevante para los sistemas operativos. Publica una nueva pregunta al respecto y allí obtendrás una respuesta al respecto (mía y/o de otra persona).

Comment: Casi termino jeje una pregunta si la carpeta donde  voy a copiar el archivo esta en raiz se declararia asi File carpetaDestino = new File("/images");  o estoy mal ?

Comment: @MissaelArmenta si la ruta empieza con `/` debes colocar la ruta completa. Te convendría más colocar algo como `C:\\carpeta\\de\imagenes` si estás en Windows, o `/opt/carpeta/de/imagenes` si trabajas en algún sitema *-nix.